# Python xpath: try an xpath, except fill in a given value

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, try-except

I'm scraping reviews from a website. Eventually I need several lists (e.g. usernames and date), which will be put in a dict per review so that it looks like this:

```
reviews:[{'username':'Harry','date':'april'},
         {'username':'Rob','date':'may'}]
```

These lists have to be equally long, since I'm putting them in a dict like this:
    reviews=[]

```
for i in range(len(username)):
    reviews.append({'username':username[i].strip(),
                              'date':date[i].strip()})
```

However, when there is no username, the xpath does not return anything and my list is too short (which will give the error "list index out of range"). How can I fill in a given value (e.g. "no name") when the xpath does not work? If have tried things like this (which I thought would work but doesn't):

```
try:
    names = tree.xpath..
except:
    "no name"
```

EDIT: examples of `HTML` for type of review(mobile vs. not mobile).
Mobile review:

```
<div class="rating reviewItemInline">
  <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span>
  <span class="ratingDate relativeDate">Reviewed 6 days ago</span>
  <a class="viaMobile">via mobile</a>
</div>
```

Non-mobile review:

```
<div class="rating reviewItemInline">
  <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span>
  <span class="ratingDate relativeDate">Reviewed 6 days ago</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what package are you using for this `tree`? I assume `lxml`?

Comment: Yes I'm using lxml

Comment: Can you share `HTML`/`XML` both for element with empty and not empty `"username"`?

Comment: @Andersson I've have added an example of the `HTML` for mobile vs. non-mobile reviews (not sure how to share `HTML`, hope you understand it)

Comment: Considering provided samples do you want output as `reviews:[{'viaMobile':'via mobile','date':'Reviewed 6 days ago'},
         {'viaMobile':' no ','date':'Reviewed 6 days ago'}]` or what exactly? It still not quite clear...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what kind of output I need! In general I want to know how I can tell python to fill in a specific line of text (in this case: 'not mobile'), when the given xpath is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need in implementing `try`/`except`, just try to get two lists of all  required elements as below:

```
html = lxml.html.fromstring("source code here")
reviews = html.xpath('//div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]')
dates = [i.xpath('./span[@class="ratingDate relativeDate"]')[0].text for i in reviews]
mobile = [i.xpath('./a')[0].text if i.xpath('./a') else "no" for i in reviews]
output = [{'date': i, 'via mobile': j} for i, j in zip(dates, mobile)]
```

The `output` should be something like

```
[{'date': 'Reviewed 6 days ago', 'via mobile': 'via mobile'}, {'date': 'Reviewed 6 days ago', 'via mobile': 'no'}]
```

Comment: This was very helpful. However, I get back NoneType objects for `i.xpath('./a')[0].text`. My output looks like this `['no', None, 'no', 'no', 'no']`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does original structure in HTML differs from provided samples?

Comment: Hmm... It worked for me fine. Does it returns you `None` both for relativeDate and viaMobile?

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate on the items you want, and then check the xpath necessary per field, something like:

```
review_elems = tree_html.xpath('//div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]')

reviews = []   

for review_elem in reviews_elems:
    review = {}
    username = review_elem.xpath('.//a[@class="viaMobile"]')
    if username:
        review['username'] = username[0].text
    else:
        review['username'] = 'no name'

    # keep filling review with more fields
    reviews.append(review)

print(reviews)
```